# Is it possible to deploy SP 2010 Timer Job to SP 2013 farm?

Tags: 2013, migration, custom-timer-job

Within a 2010 farm I've got a **custom timer job**. The timer job is installed/activated via web application feature.

Now I need to provide the timer job's functionality/results to **site collections running in 2010 mode on a 2013 farm**. These 2010 site collections exist side by side with 2013 site collections in a single web application.

Is it possible to deploy my 2010 timer job to a 2013 farm using the "old" WSP-file (using `Install-SPSolution ... -CompatibilityLevel 14`) and activate the feature within the web application?

If so, I can configure/administrate the 2010 timer job from the Central Administration of the 2013 farm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you should be able to deploy the timer job using the old WSP and it should work properly for sites in SP 2010 mode. However, as is expected if you need it in SP 2013 sites then you will have to update the WSP to be in conformance with SP 2013.